# How to design database in order to store "default" items

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, database-design

I'm developing an app in Laravel. I've models called Account and ShippingAddress. An Account may have one or more ShippingAddress, but a ShippingAddress can only have one Account. So that I'm using a one-to-many relation.

Now I want to implement a functionality that marks a ShippingAddress as "default", and there's can be only one "default Shipping Address" per "Account". I've identified two possible solutions:

1. Add a "is_default" column on ShippingAddress table.
2. Create a "default_shipping_address" pivot table where I'll store the "account_id" "and shipping_address_id".

Which one is the best solution up to you and why? In case of the second one: how can I implement a one-to-one relation in Laravel through a pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO using a pivot table seems a bit redundant considering that one `ShippingAddress` belongs to only one `Account`, the first solution looks cleaner to me.

BTW you can design the `Models` in this way or something like:

```php
class Account extends Model
{
    public function shipping_addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ShippingAddress');
    }
    public function default_shipping_address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ShippingAddress')->where('is_default', true);
    }
}

class ShippingAddress extends Model
{
    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
    }
}
```

In this way you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `'shipping_addresses'` or only `'default_shipping_address'` when you retrieve the `Account` model, e.g.:

```php
$account = Account::with('shipping_addresses')->find($id);
$account = Account::with('default_shipping_address')->find($id);
```

Obviously you should not need to `eager load` both the relationships togheter because `shipping_addresses` already include the *defaut shipping address*.

You have only to check that there is only **one** `default shipping address` in your code either with validation ([unique rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique)) or database [constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-indexes) or both.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 1 because it is simpler and has no downsides. In order to make sure you have only one default `ShippingAddress` per `Account` you listen for the `saving` event and do some validation like:

```
class ShippingAddress extends Model
{
    // ... other code

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function (ShippingAddress $shippingAddress) {
            if (! $shippingAddress->is_default) {
                return;
            }

            $defaultAlreadyExists = static::where([
                ['account_id', '=', $shippingAddress->account_id],
                ['id', '!=', $shippingAddress->id],
                ['is_default', '=', true],
            ])->exists();

            if ($defaultAlreadyExists) {
                throw new YourCustomException("Account with id {$shippingAddress->account_id} already has a default shipping address");
            }
        });
    }

    // ... other code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

my personal point of view, is that in the case of a single favorite address, using a pivot table, although it may be more correct from the formal, would only be adding a complication to the query. Instead by adding a flag column to the address to determine when it is favorite, it would make the query easier.

Now, if you want to use a pivot table, you should establish a relationship in Account model using a function such as:

```
public function defaultShippingAddress()
    {
      return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Models\AccountShippingAddress', 'App\Models\ShippingAddress');
    }
```

Here you can read the whole documentation about it https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Regards.

Comment: I would like to explore this answer, but I didn't quite understand it. I'll design my DB as follow: `accounts [id, ...]`, `shipping_addresses [id, account_id, ...]`, `default_shipping_address [account_id, shipping_address_id]`. Now I create a `DefaultShippingAddress` that extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` because by reading the docs it sounds like the right thing to do. Then I implement the method you suggested, by inverting the parameters. But if I try to execute the method it returns a `QueryException`: it cannot retrieve `shipping_addresses.id`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let me try to implement your models and I'll be back with a better explanation.